# Pass touch events to child view using react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native, gesture, react-native-ios

I am using this [React-Native-Gesture-Handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/) for handling my gesture user do on the app.

But the gesture seems to not work as expected or some functionality seems to be not there to pass on the Gesture events to the Child view

Here the Heriracy

```
              <PanGestureHandler
            {...this.props}
            ref={this.panRef}
            onGestureEvent={this._onGestureEvent}
            onHandlerStateChange={this._onPanHandlerStateChange}>
            <Animated.View
                onLayout={this._onLayout}
                style={[this.props.style,
                this.props.windowSize,
                this.props.isFullScreen ? {} : {
                    transform: [
                        { translateX: this._translateX },
                        { translateY: this._translateY },
                    ],
               }]}>
                    <View style={styles.wrapper}>       ----> Child View
                        {this.props.children}
                    </View>
            </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
```

In this example the whole view is wrapped with a Pan Gesture
this Pan gesture is used to move the view around the screen-space.

Other than this Child view here would also contain view which will have some pan gesture implementations.
If this pan gesture events gets cancelled out because of the outer pan gesture.

Is there any way to get the inner child view's pan gesture events correctly?

I m unable to find any solution to the pass these parent gesture event to the child and cancel out the parent gesture actions.

If you need any more info about the whole issue... please do ask.